# Rsyslog stop working when output destination (rabbitmq) is unavialable

Tags: rabbitmq, rsyslog

I have rsyslog (8.2310.0) in docker container from latest alpine image as a syslog collector with forwarding to logstash.local and rabbitmq.local

Rsyslog stops working when rabbitmq is unavialable and work fine when rabbitmq server is up

How to configure rsyslog to skip destination unavialable ?

```
module(load="omrabbitmq")
module(load="imptcp" threads="3")
input(type="imptcp" port="514" ruleset="syslogCollector")

template(
    name="json_syslog"
    type="list"
    option.json="on"
) {
    constant(value="{")
    constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")       property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value="\",\"type\":\"syslog_json")
    constant(value="\",\"tag\":\"")           property(name="syslogtag" format="json")
    constant(value="\",\"relayhost\":\"")     property(name="fromhost")
    constant(value="\",\"relayip\":\"")       property(name="fromhost-ip")
    constant(value="\",\"logsource\":\"")     property(name="source")
    constant(value="\",\"hostname\":\"")      property(name="hostname" caseconversion="lower")
    constant(value="\",\"program\":\"")       property(name="programname")
    constant(value="\",\"source\":\"")        property(name="app-name" caseConversion="lower" onEmpty="null")
    constant(value="\",\"priority\":\"")      property(name="pri")
    constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")      property(name="syslogseverity" caseConversion="upper")
    constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")      property(name="syslogfacility")
    constant(value="\",\"severity_label\":\"")   property(name="syslogseverity-text")
    constant(value="\",\"facility_label\":\"")   property(name="syslogfacility-text")
    constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")       property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\",\"end_msg\":\"")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}

ruleset(
    name="syslogCollector"
) {
   @@elk.local:5000;json_syslog
   call send2mqtt
}

ruleset (
    name="send2mqtt"

    queue.type="LinkedList"
    queue.size="1024"
    queue.dequeueBatchSize="512"
    queue.filename="q_mqtt"
    queue.saveonshutdown="off"
    queue.highwatermark="450"
    queue.lowwatermark="50"

) {
    action(
        type="omrabbitmq"
        host="rabbitmq.local"
        verify_peer="off"
        verify_hostname="off"
        virtual_host="/"
        user="xxx"
        password="xxx"
        exchange="syslog"
        routing_key="messages"
        body_template="json_syslog"

        action.resumeRetryCount="0"
        action.reportSuspension="on"
        action.reportSuspensionContinuation="on"
        action.resumeInterval="10"
    )
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when "Rsyslog stops working when rabbitmq is unavailable"? Does the rsyslog service itself stop running, or does it just stop forwarding logs to RabbitMQ? Please elaborate on how you expect rsyslog to handle log forwarding when RabbitMQ is unavailable.